# How to find out who and when created taxonomy term

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

Is it possible to know who and when created taxonomy term? Is that information stored anywhere?

I can't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not in Drupal core. Unlike the [Node entity](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/function/Node%3A%3AbaseFieldDefinitions/8.2.x), the [Taxonomy term entity](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21Entity%21Term.php/function/Term%3A%3AbaseFieldDefinitions/8.2.x) does not define a field that stores a field denoting ownership. You'll need to add your own field to your taxonomy terms to give them an ownership property.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping I missed something. S*cks when you find out too late.